# How to make Ubuntu MATE 21.04 remember my default application for .desktop files in context menu?

Tags: mate, default-programs, 21.04

System: Ubuntu Mate 21.04

I wish to have the default choice in the context menu for editing .desktop files be `pluma`. But MATE refuses to honor my wishes! How can I bend it to my will?

This shows the default choice of Libreoffice

[image]

I choose "open with other application" and select `pluma`. The "remember this application" box is ticked.

[image]

But the next time I do it, Libreoffice is still the default.

How to make `pluma` the default context menu item for editing .desktop files?

Per request, here is `~/.config/mimeapps.list`:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
text/html=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop
application/x-extension-eml=thunderbird.desktop
message/rfc822=thunderbird.desktop
inode/directory=caja-folder-handler.desktop
text/plain=pluma.desktop
audio/mpeg=rhythmbox.desktop
audio/x-mpegurl=rhythmbox.desktop
audio/x-scpls=rhythmbox.desktop
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=rhythmbox.desktop
audio/x-wav=rhythmbox.desktop
video/mp4=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/mpeg=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/mp2t=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/msvideo=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/quicktime=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/webm=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/x-avi=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/x-flv=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/x-matroska=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/x-mpeg=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
video/x-ogm+ogg=io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop
image/bmp=eom.desktop
image/gif=eom.desktop
image/jpeg=eom.desktop
image/png=eom.desktop
image/tiff=eom.desktop
application/pdf=atril.desktop
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text=libreoffice-writer.desktop
application/msword=libreoffice-writer.desktop
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=libreoffice-writer.desktop
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/vnd.ms-excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/x-desktop=pluma.desktop
application/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop
application/x-shellscript=pluma.desktop

[Added Associations]
audio/mpeg=vlc.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-mpegurl=vlc.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-scpls=vlc.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=vlc.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-wav=vlc.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
video/mp4=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/mpeg=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/mp2t=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/msvideo=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/quicktime=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/webm=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/x-avi=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/x-flv=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/x-matroska=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/x-mpeg=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
video/x-ogm+ogg=vlc.desktop;io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.desktop;
application/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
```

@nobody in a comment suggested I try the Properties entry in the context menu. Here's where it really gets weird. To begin with, it looked like this.

[image]

I thought victory was within my grasp! I deleted Libreoffice and the box beside Pluma was checked. Surely that would work!  But *NO*, rejection, now the context menu has *no default, it only shows Open With Other Application*  At this point I'm starting to think someone does not want me to open these with Pluma!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the contents of `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file. And maybe ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ too .

Comment: Have you tried unter properties to remove the libre office entries? I hope this is possible in ubuntu too.

Comment: @nobody thank you for the suggestion! For a second I thought it was going to work. But it didn't, see edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it to work, but there is really something going on I don't understand. See the question for details.

To get it work, I clicked here

[image]

and entered `pluma` for the custom command.  Now it works!

Note: *You cannot have pluma selected at the left when you enter the custom command, or it **will not work***

That's just weird.

[image]

Thanks to the commenters who helped me solve it.

Comment: Seems really strange. I have reported this to launchpad as [bug 1929307](https://pad.lv/1929307), you can subscribe and maybe add more details.

Comment: @N0rbert will do, thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a general error in mate in Debian i struggle sometimes with similar behavior